# Facebook Graph API request groups access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

How can I access the groups via Graph API?

I'm using version 2.11

I have the permissions that I need:
[image]

But when I'm traying to access "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/" I've obtain an empty data.
[image]

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

With user_managed_groups permission, this request only returns your managed groups. Means you are already accessing it. Hope this documentation will help you:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/group

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure if you understand my question or not... So I will try to explain it again. 1. I do not have access to my `me/groups` how you can see in the first picture. 2. how could get the access to that `me/groups`? I've try to get the all permissions and still I can not do anything.

Comment: Are you sure that you manage any group from the same  id from which you are accessing the groups?

Comment: may be you have a group you are managing from one of your account but you have an access token from another account

Comment: I just want to get data from the groups that I'm in... I'm not admin on any kind of group

Comment: That is not possible. If you read the documentation it will state that

Comment: ok, then it's not possible till API version 2.11. May be in future.